# seeing the contents of a zipped file which contains square brackets

Tags: bash, sed, unzip, brackets

```
x=`unzip -l "$i" | grep /config.xml | tail -1 | sed -e "s/.*:[0-9][0-9] *//"`
content=`unzip -c "$i" "$x" | DO MORE STUFF HERE
```

I am having a problem with the above command whenever x outputs a string with square brackets. For example, let's say that after running the x line, $x = "Refresher [Autosaved]/xml/config.xml". If I pass $x to the content line, I get an error that `caution: filename not matched: Refresher [Autosaved]/xml/config.xml`. I have tried updating the sed command to escape the brackets with `s/\[\([^]]*\)\]/\\\[\1\\\]/g` and the values echo out fine, but when I save it to x, the `\[` and `\]` turns into just `[` and `]` and I am back to square one.

How can I run the content command if my x value has square brackets?

Comment: It would be a lot saner to use tools like the Python `zipfile` module that let you work directly with the names as literals, rather than trying to pick content out of a stream of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself a ton of trouble using modern `$(...)` instead of legacy `` `...` ``. The former does not require additional escaping:

```
$ x=$(echo 'Foo [Bar].baz' | sed "s/\[\([^]]*\)\]/\\\[\1\\\]/g")
$ printf '%s\n' "$x"
Foo \[Bar\].baz


$ x=`echo 'Foo [Bar].baz' | sed "s/\[\([^]]*\)\]/\\\[\1\\\]/g"`
$ printf '%s\n' "$x"
Foo [Bar].baz
```